# Wrapping and integrating an existing Python `socket`-based class with `asyncio`

Tags: python, tcp, python-asyncio, python-sockets

I have a use-case where there are a lot of TCP/IP clients being bundled up into a single Python process. The current desire is to use `asyncio` to provide concurrency for the program. For all *new* TCP/IP clients, [`asyncio` streams](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html) will be used, and for all new HTTP clients, [`aiohttp`](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/) will be used.

However, there are several *existing* clients that are written using Python's [`socket`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html) module. My question is: how should you "wrap" the existing `socket`-based classes and methods with `async`?

---

Example existing TCP/IP client:

```py
import socket

class ExistingClient:
    def __init__(self, host: str, port: int) -> None:
        self.__host = host
        self.__port = port
        self.__socket: socket.socket | None = None

    def initialize(self) -> None:
        self.__socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.__socket.connect((self.__host, self.__port))

    def get_status(self) -> int:
        self.__socket.send("2\n".encode())
        data: str = str(self.__socket.recv(1024).decode()).strip()
        return int(data)

    def close(self) -> None:
        self.__socket.close()
```

##### Example TCP/IP server

You can run this server script to serve as an example for the below client script. Save in `server.py`.

```py
import asyncio
import functools

class State:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.__count: int = 0

    def add_to_count(self, count: int) -> None:
        self.__count = self.__count + count

    @property
    def count(self) -> int:
        return self.__count


async def handle_echo(
    reader: asyncio.StreamReader, writer: asyncio.StreamWriter, state: State
):
    # Ignore the use of the infinite while loop for this example.
    # Controlling the loop would be handled in a more sophisticated way.
    while True:
        data = await reader.readline()
        message: int = int(data.decode())
        state.add_to_count(message)

        addr = writer.get_extra_info("peername")

        writer.write(f"{state.count}\n".encode())
        await writer.drain()

    writer.close()
    await writer.wait_closed()


async def server(port: int):
    state = State()
    partial = functools.partial(handle_echo, state=state)
    server = await asyncio.start_server(partial, "127.0.0.1", port)

    address = ", ".join(str(sock.getsockname()) for sock in server.sockets)
    print(f"Serving on {address}")

    async with server:
        await server.serve_forever()


async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(
        server(8888),
        server(8889),
    )

asyncio.run(main())
```

##### Possible solution 1

To me, one solution seems to be that the existing class(es) could be editing with `async` methods that simply defer down to the blocking I/O `socket` calls. For example:

```py
import socket

class ExistingClient:
    def __init__(self, host: str, port: int) -> None:
        self.__host = host
        self.__port = port
        self.__socket: socket.socket | None = None

    def initialize(self) -> None:
        self.__socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.__socket.connect((self.__host, self.__port))

    async def async_initialize(self) -> None:
        self.initialize()

    def get_status(self) -> int:
        self.__socket.send("2\n".encode())
        data: str = str(self.__socket.recv(1024).decode()).strip()
        return int(data)

    async def async_get_status(self) -> int:
        return self.get_status()

    def close(self) -> None:
        self.__socket.close()

    async def async_close(self) -> None:
        self.close()
```

Does this work in the sense of not blocking the `asyncio` event loop such that it behaves very similarly to `asyncio` streams calls? As an example of how I envision something like this getting integrated with normal `asyncio` code (saved in the same file as the directly above modified `ExistingClient` with the `async` methods in say `client.py`):

```py
import asyncio

async def streams_tcp_client():
    reader, writer = await asyncio.open_connection("127.0.0.1", 8888)

    writer.write("1\n".encode())
    await writer.drain()

    data: bytes = await reader.readline()
    print(f"asyncio streams data: {data.decode().strip()}")

    writer.close()
    await writer.wait_closed()


async def existing_tcp_client1():
    existing_client = ExistingClient("127.0.0.1", 8889)
    await existing_client.async_initialize()

    data: int = await existing_client.async_get_status()
    print(f"Existing client data: {data}")

    await existing_client.async_close()


async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(
        streams_tcp_client(),
        existing_tcp_client1(),
    )
```

Does this work as one might expect it to such that the `ExistingClient` `async` calls, that contain blocking I/O calls, *do not block* the `asyncio` event loop?

I have ran this code, and it runs and prints out the expected data. But it is unclear how to test if the event loop is running as expected or desired.

---

##### Possible solution 2

I have seen some mention of [`asyncio.to_thread`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.to_thread). In the documentation, it states:

> This coroutine function is primarily intended to be used for executing IO-bound functions/methods that would otherwise block the event loop if they were run in the main thread.

However, this does not really explain anything. And it doesn't explain why simply defining

```py
async def async_blocking_io():
    blocking_io()
```

is not enough to not block the event loop. Because the actual blocking I/O, such as a TCP/IP write and read operation, shouldn't block the event loop's thread, correct?

Would the way to use this be the following:

```py
async def existing_tcp_client2():
    existing_client = ExistingClient("127.0.0.1", 8889)
    await asyncio.to_thread(existing_client.initialize)

    data: int = await asyncio.to_thread(existing_client.get_status)
    print(f"Existing client data with to_thread: {data}")

    await asyncio.to_thread(existing_client.close)
```

This runs if I modify `main` to be:

```py
async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(
        streams_tcp_client(),
        existing_tcp_client1(),
    )
```

---

#### Final thoughts

What is the difference between making `async def async_<existing_method>` methods vs the `asyncio.to_thread` method? The `asyncio.to_thread` method is concerning, because each call would be ran in a new thread? That could be an issue for thread-unsafe classes and also creates overhead by constantly spawning new threads.

What are the other solutions to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution 1 - simply wrapping synchronous functions with an `async` wrapper - will still block your main process. In a TCP server/client you could try to work around this by rewriting the lower level functions where you send/read data to/from the socket, making those lower level functions also async, processing the communication in smaller chunks. But if you don't do that, then solution 1 cannot give you more concurrency.

If you simply define

```
async def async_blocking_io():
    blocking_io()
```

then that is going to block the process. Even if you add a formal await statement like this:

```
async def async_blocking_io():
    await asyncio.sleep(0) # first gives other tasks a chance
    blocking_io()
```

Now other co-routines might run first, but you're still going to block in the synchronous `blocking_io()` call because the underlying TCP read and write operations are also synchronous and do block (if you put the socket in non-blocking mode, you'd need blocking select calls to know when data is available).

The `asyncio.to_thread` function does run in a separate thread since this is the only way to prevent blocking (when using a simple high-level wrapper). So, if you  call this often, you will indeed have lots of overhead, and this may defeat the purpose of using asyncio.

There is no easy way out. Either you select the convenience of `asyncio.to_thread` (with it's overhead) or you go all the way in and rewrite all code, including the existing clients, using `asyncio.streams` or you go half-way in by making the existing high-level synchronous code async (but this will only help if you can also make their lowest level functions -- communications with the sockets -- async).

Comment: Thank you so much! I think I'm actually understanding now. The `socket` functions used here are blocking in the sense that they block the thread they run on. While they reach out to the OS to make the actual network call, which releases the GIL, it only releases the GIL for *other* threads and *not* the thread that it is running on. So when the `socket` calls are simply wrapped with `async`, they are blocking the event loop by blocking the thread it is running on. The `asyncio` streams implements a non-blocking TCP/IP library, probably reading things byte by byte into a stream, hence the name.

Comment: Is that the correct understanding? I did end up testing this, by having the test server delay the server response by 3 seconds for a special message. The `existing_tcp_client1` method (wrapping with `async`) did indeed block all three coroutines, while `existing_tcp_client2` took three seconds to return but did not block the other two coroutines from returning as soon as they were done.

Comment: Yes, that is also my understanding.

Comment: In the https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/asyncio/streams.py implementation, you can see that the high-level async streams impl is based on a buffered synchronous underlying transport layer. The buffering makes it possible to make the high-level calls async.

Comment: Thanks again! So in terms of how to adapt the existing system, it seems strange to just keep going using the old `socket` library. Does it make sense to use `asyncio` for new code, defer to `asyncio.to_thread` for old code (with the possibility of rewriting it, if time allows using `asyncio`)? We'd probably also have an instance of `ProcessPoolExecutor` for `asyncio.run_in_executor`. I guess the larger question is: does centering the design around `asyncio` generally make sense for modern, single-process, concurrent Python?

Comment: Imo it does make sense to use asyncio for the new code and to use `asyncio.to_thread` to wrap older code -- that would be the fastest way forward. But if you control the old code (are able to change the implementation), I would in a second step gradually rewrite this too. I once did sth similar for a smaller TCP client library that originally was completely synchronous. For this you could model your code on how the asyncio.streams library is built on top of the transport abstraction.  For I/O bound concurrency asyncio makes a lot of sense. (Note also that GIL-less Python is in the making...)

Comment: Yea, I'm relatively new to Python in terms of writing a big system with it, as I come from other languages like F# and Elixir (hence my confusion on how these concurrency models in Python work). But it does seem like `asyncio` is the best "central" or "glue" solution when primarily dealing with a lot of I/O, since it can defer out to threads or `multiprocessing` if needed.

Thanks again for the help here. Your explanation is the only one I've found that dove into the actual "why?" and got me to understand it. Much appreciated.

Comment: Btw - If you have more questions of this kind or questions about design - questions that may not be considered very acceptable on StackOverflow - then discuss.python.org is an excellent forum (all the Python core devs are also there).

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion! I may make a post there to gut check myself on a design I'm working on.